# PDO search query, make it like Android contacts search

Tags: php, android, sql, search, pdo

I have tried to implement search in my gadget using `LIKE` query.

Now I have a new requirement where I have to make this search like the Android Search..

Query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ROOM, GUEST_NAME, GUEST_FIRST_NAME, CONFIRMATION_NO, DEPARTURE, PWD FROM RESERVATION_GENERAL_2 WHERE LOWER(GUEST_FIRST_NAME) LIKE ? OR LOWER(GUEST_NAME) LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(array('%'.strtolower($searchFilter).'%','%'.strtolower($searchFilter).'%' ));
```

Let's suppose I have a string `Syed Haider Hassan` in database
and if I search `san` in the database table using the given query, it will find me this above string. Hence if I put anything that matches inside or anywhere in string it will get me this string.

But what I want is that when I search in database `Hai` or `Has` or `Sy` it should get me this string, but if  search `san` or even `assan`, the query should not show me the this string.
Means if search it must do search with `startwith`,  not from middle.
I think it might be possible if I remove `%` from start, but problem is then query will only see startwith on Syed, I want it apply startwith on every word as words are separated by space. Search `Syed` `Haider` `Hassan` differently.

But in simple words if you have Android Mobile, I have Galaxy S4, search any name in your contacts book. If you search from middle of word it will not search but if you search from start of word it will search, but that's just not it. If your contact name is combination of two words separated by space then it will also check for first Alphabet of second word.

How can I update my query to this new search criteria?

### Update

I tried the match against as suggested in one of answer using try catch, I get this error:

[image]

Here is the code I tried:

```
$search_words = "+" . str_replace (" ", "* +", $searchFilter )."*";
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ROOM, GUEST_NAME, GUEST_FIRST_NAME, CONFIRMATION_NO, DEPARTURE, PWD FROM RESERVATION_GENERAL_2 WHERE MATCH (GUEST_FIRST_NAME, GUEST_NAME) against (:SEARCH in boolean mode)");
            $stmt->bindValue(':SEARCH', $search_words, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

How can I solve it?

### Update 2

Simply I put the facts here. Here is my table structure:

[image]

If I use like with wildcard %%, it will search for even from middle of name.

Let's see the highlighted name in screenshot, the highlighted name is `Lukasz Henryk`.

If I search with wild card using like %enry%, it will find me this row.
but I don't want that, I want search should word with start of name.
e-g if I search `Luk` or `Hen` or `He` or even `H`, it should find me this row. Means starting alphabet is important, if starting alphabet don't match then don't give me the row.

I also tried a wildcard like query like this `Henr%` but it doesn't work because like this it only works for `Luk%`, it consider whole column as single string.

Is there a way to tell query to search for starting alphabet after space?

Answer (score 1):

As other said the fulltext index is the way to go this is what you want your query to look like, the `+` makes all words required leave it out for looking up any words.  You cannot use the `"` double quote, with the `*` wildcard, which is reasonable because the double quote means `exact` word.  Which it cannot be when using the wild card. ( or at least I have yet to find a way to do it )

```
SELECT
    ROOM,
    GUEST_NAME,
    GUEST_FIRST_NAME,
    CONFIRMATION_NO,
    DEPARTURE,
    PWD
FROM
    RESERVATION_GENERAL_2
WHERE
    MATCH(GUEST_NAME, GUEST_FIRST_NAME)
AGAINST
    ( '+word* +word2*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

Basically

```
  $search_words = '';
 foreach( explode(' ', $search) as $words ){
       $search_words .= '+'.$word.'* ';
 }
```

AND

```
...
WHERE
    MATCH(GUEST_NAME, GUEST_FIRST_NAME)
AGAINST
    ( :search_words IN BOOLEAN MODE )

 $stmt->bindValue(':search_words', $search_words, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Etc...

But you have to have a full text index, in this case a composite one on `GUEST_NAME, GUEST_FIRST_NAME`.

See also this

[MySQL Full Text Search Mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840346/mysql-full-text-search-mystery)

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL:s MATCH AGAINST. Remember that you have to make a FULLTEXT index containing the GUEST_FIRST_NAME and GUEST_NAME (in this order).

Just an example:

```
$string = "syed haider";
$search_words = "+" . str_replace (" ", "* +", $string )."*";

$query = "SELECT ROOM, GUEST_NAME, GUEST_FIRST_NAME, CONFIRMATION_NO, DEPARTURE, PWD FROM RESERVATION_GENERAL_2 WHERE MATCH (GUEST_FIRST_NAME) against ('$search_words' in boolean mode) OR MATCH (GUEST_NAME) against ('$search_words' in boolean mode)";

// SELECT ROOM, GUEST_NAME, GUEST_FIRST_NAME, CONFIRMATION_NO, DEPARTURE, PWD FROM RESERVATION_GENERAL_2 WHERE MATCH (GUEST_FIRST_NAME) against ('+syed* +haider*' in boolean mode) OR MATCH (GUEST_NAME) against ('+syed* +haider*' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: can you please make this query work in pdo. if possible update my query. i am not good with database queries..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried mysql regexp (rlike)?

table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `user` (`name`)
VALUES
    ('Syed Haider Hassan');
```

query:

```
select * from user where name rlike '[[:<:]]Hass'
```

returns:

```
name
Syed Haider Hassan
```

not matching query:

```
select * from user where name rlike '[[:<:]]san'
```

returns:

```
name
```

Comment: Rlike can be really slow and mess up indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from search string ($search_words = "+" . str_replace (" ", "* +", $searchFilter )."*";), cause relational operator is "+,-,< >, etc.", that's why you need first see your complete query.

Make this steps:

1. echo your sql query and try to execute in some MySql GUI (e.g. Navicat) for be sure that your query haven't errors.
2. Be sure GUEST_FIRST_NAME, GUEST_NAME fields index is "Full Text". For that you need to execute "ALTER TABLE `RESERVATION_GENERAL_2`
   ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `name_index` (`GUEST_FIRST_NAME`, `GUEST_NAME`) ;"

Try this steps and let me know.